# Div centered on cursor, acting as cursor for image-hover-zoom effect

Tags: javascript

[image]

So I have a target div (large rectangle) which would be the target image. You'd hover over this, and you'd get a square that replaces the cursor with a portion of a larger/higher-resolution version of the same image.

I have the tracking down, and I've offset so that the div is centered on the cursor's position but the problem is, the target div can no longer be picked up, until the cursor leaves the overlay (goes outside of the square).

How can I get around this? Is it possible to replace the cursor with the div and still use the cursor?

I'm thinking just use the top-left coordinate of the big rectangle and go off that... still I don't know. Can you replace the cursor with a canvas object for example? I might still face the problem of not detecting the target div. I tried z-index that doesn't work.

edit: I might just hide the cursor and go to the left corner of the overlay square so it appears that you're centered over whatever you're supposedly pointing at.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // declare variables
      var target   = document.getElementById("target-area"),// $("#target-area") doesn't work?
          cursWind = $("#cursor-window"),
          prevX    = 0,
          prevY    = 0,
          cursX    = 0,
          cursY    = 0;
      // tracking
      // client is using a mouse
      target.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
        // run the tracking only while mouse is over the sensor range area
        target.addEventListener("mousemove", function ( event ) {

          /* when the mouse goes over target, a window with the center
           * at the cursor's position, should appear, this follows
             the cursor */


          /* cursor coordinates */
          // get cursor's current X and Y coordinates
          cursX = event.clientX;
          cursY = event.clientY;
          var coordString = cursX + " x" + "," + cursY + " y";
          // empty cursor-coord-disp
          $("#cursor-coord-disp").empty();
          // append X and Y coordinates to cursor-coord-disp
          $("#cursor-coord-disp").append(coordString);

          /* see if cursor is increasing or decreasing in x/y coordinates */
          // x-coord
          function checkX() {
            if (cursX > prevX) {
              prevX = cursX; // update old x-coord
              return ((-1) * cursX);
            }
            else {
              prevX = cursX; // update old x-coord
              return cursX;
            }
          }

          function checkY() {
            if (cursY > prevY) {
              prevY = cursY; // update old x-coord
              return ((-1) * cursY);
            }
            else {
              prevY = cursY; // update old x-coord
              return cursY;
            }
          }

          /* window replaces and follows cursor position */
          // get X and Y top-left coordinates of target-area
          var targPos = $("#target-area").position(),
              targX   = targPos.left,
              targY   = targPos.top;
          // console.log(targX + " vs " + targY);
          // show the hovering window that follows cursor
          $("#cursor-window").show();
          // reposition to cursor with offset
          // console.log(checkX());
          var newXCoord   = (event.clientX),
              newYCoord   = (event.clientY);
          console.log(newXCoord + ' vs ' + newYCoord);
          // translate to cursor position
          $("#cursor-window").css({
            'top'  : newYCoord - 150,
            'left' : newXCoord - 150
          });

        }, false);
      }, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't you want to use existing implementations?
for example http://redopop.com/loupe/

Comment: @YuriGor You've got a point. I am kinda just trying to get this thing done. I might very well just do that. I started to get close with canvas. I just don't completely understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following code and markup. The position is calculated by subtracting the position of the target div from the mouse cursor position in the page. The cursor window is visible only when the mouse is inside the target div limits.

```js
var $target = $("#target-area"),
    $cursorWindow = $("#cursor-window"),
    $coordsDisplay = $("#cursor-coord-disp");

var zoomFactor = 2;

// Copy the background image to the zoom window
$cursorWindow.css('background-image', $target.css('background-image'));
$cursorWindow.css('background-repeat', $target.css('background-repeat'));

$target.mousemove(function (e) {
    var $targetPosition = $target.position();
    var cursX = e.pageX - $targetPosition.left;
    var cursY = e.pageY - $targetPosition.top;
    var imgX, imgY, imgW, imgH;

    if (0 <= cursX && cursX <= $target.outerWidth() && 0 <= cursY && cursY <= $target.outerHeight()) {
        $cursorWindow.css({
            'left': cursX - $cursorWindow.outerWidth() / 2,
            'top': cursY - $cursorWindow.outerHeight() / 2
        });
        $cursorWindow.show();
        $coordsDisplay.text("x: " + cursX.toFixed(0) + ", y: " + cursY.toFixed(0));

        imgX = -(cursX * zoomFactor) + $cursorWindow.innerWidth() / 2;
        imgY = -(cursY * zoomFactor) + $cursorWindow.innerHeight() / 2;

        imgW = $target.innerWidth() * zoomFactor;
        imgH = $target.innerHeight() * zoomFactor;

        // Change the position and size of the image in the zoom window
        // to show a magnified view of the image content under the cursor
        $cursorWindow.css('background-position', imgX.toFixed(0) + 'px ' + imgY.toFixed(0) + 'px');
        $cursorWindow.css('background-size', imgW.toFixed(0) + 'px ' + imgH.toFixed(0) + 'px');
    } else {
        $cursorWindow.hide();
        $coordsDisplay.text("");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor-coord-disp" style="width: 140px; height: 24px; border: solid 1px black;"></div>
<div id="target-area" style="cursor: none; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 10px; width: 320px; height: 240px; background: url('http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog') no-repeat; border: solid 1px black; ">
    <div id="cursor-window" style="display: none; cursor: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 80px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px black;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. It was actually easier using canvas, it worked as I expected/figured but using divs not so much.

Comment: It may be easier with a canvas. For the sake of completeness, I added actual image zooming in my code snippet. You can see how it could work with a div.

Comment: By the way, a different image is loaded every time we run the code snippet. I was afraid that the image in the zoom window could be different from the one in the target div but I haven't seen that problem in my tests.

Comment: Wow you actually made it work. Awesome. Did you use slice? I'll have to analyze your code. I went with Loupe and once I figured out how to use it, now my problem is I can't reset the source of the zoomed image. Even dissected the code and reset the image attribute src manually. hmmm

Comment: I fixed the loupe problem I had with the changing of the source, I had to target the loupe class, then the img child, and then change the source there.

Comment: It was much easier to implement that I first thought (otherwise, I would have done it in the first version of my answer). I don't know what you mean by "slice". I just copy the background image to the zoom window and use CSS background settings to get the magnifier effect, as you can see in the code snippet.

Comment: I thought you might have been using canvas. Anyway thanks for your help.